# Does cooling of a hygroscopic polymer placed with dessicant in a sealed chamber positively impact the moisture removal?

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, temperature, water

I want to remove moisture from common polymers used for 3d printing (PLA, ABS, PETG, Nylon) by placing them in a sealed chamber with desiccant (silica gel or molecular sieves).

A small fridge would be perfect for that application as they are airtight and cheaply available.

I wonder what would be an effect of powering the fridge on the moisture transfer process?

Would a lower temperature accelerate moisture transfer from less to more absorbent material?

My theory about this:

- as the air cools down the vapour capacity decreases and intuitively the more absorbent material would be the recipient of more moisture removed from the air
- as the vapour capacity decreases, the air's ability to transfer the moisture is likely to be impacted. With the extreme temperatures presumably the air would stop its function as a medium allowing transfer of the moisture from polymer to desiccant.

Do the above hold? If so, does it mean the optimal way to dehydrate polymer with desiccant is to cycle the temperature?